# Slow stored MySQL function gets progressively slower with repeated runs

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, stored-functions

I need to filter a list by whether the person has an appointment. This runs in 0.09 seconds.

```
select personid from persons p
where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM appointments a
                    WHERE a.personid = p.personid);
```

Since I use this in more than one query and it actually contains another condition, it seemed convenient to put the filter into a function, so I have

```
CREATE FUNCTION `has_appt`(pid INT) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
RETURN 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM appointments WHERE personid = pid);
END
```

Then I can use

```
select personid from persons where has_appt(personid)
```

However, two unexpected things happen. First, the statement using the has_appt() function now takes 2.5 seconds to run. I know there is overhead to a function call, but this seems extreme. Second, if I run the statement repeatedly, it takes about 5 seconds longer each time, so by the 4th time, it is taking over 20 seconds. This happens regardless of how long I wait between tries, but storing the function again resets the time to 2.5 seconds. What can account for the progressive slowness? What state can be affected by simply running it multiple times?

I know the solution is to forget the function and just embed this into my queries, but I want to understand the principle so I can avoid making the same mistake again. Thanks in advance for you help.

I'm using MySQL 8 and Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query can be replaced by, and sped up by,

```
SELECT personid FROM appointments;
```

But the query seems dumb -- why would you want a list of all it ids of people with appointments, but no info about them?  Perhaps you over-simplified the query?

If a person might have multiple appointments, then this would be needed, and might not be as fast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT personid FROM appointments;
```

As for why the function is so slow...  Optimization does not see what is inside the function.  So `select personid from persons where has_appt(personid)` walks through the entire `persons` table, calling the function repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, I put the problem into the simplest terms to make it clear. My actual implementation of course does not simply extract personids. But making it this simple makes it clear that something very different is going on when I call a function then when I do the same thing outside the function. Either way, it walks through the whole persons table, so that is not different if I understand correctly and does not explain the discrepancy. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MikeBlyth - Is `personid` indexed in `appointments`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Now I do see that using the function forces a separate lookup of appointments for every person rather than an optimized one-pass matching that the optimizer may do. But why the increasing time on each run? And yes, appointments is indexed on persons as well as persons+date.

Comment: @MikeBlyth - There could be a lot of other, more subtle, issues.  Even if we resolve the 'simplified' query, the same technique may or may not be relevant to the "real" query.

Comment: Sure, but mainly I'm interested in the simplified one since I want to understand the principle. I'm not looking for a good optimization as much as the principle in order to learn, and I think I already understand the main point, which is that the function has to do a lookup over and over while doing it in the query may avoid that. It just seems weird that some kind of state exists, where the duration depends on how many times the query has been run.

Comment: @MikeBlyth - Frankly, I am having trouble understanding why they are not _both_ slow.

Comment: @RickJames well if Mr Blyth would post the TEXT results of an EXPLAIN we might have some clues.  SHOW CREATE TABLE for two tables would also be relevant.

Comment: I came across exactly the same problem today. A query I am running on MySQL Client (command line on the server itself), has a call to a function. First time the query completes in < 1 sec, then just re-run the same query repeatedly and the time it takes to complete grows by few seconds every single time it's run. I have tried to Google but nothing relevant so far. Why would a query slow on multiple runs? MySQL 8.0.15 on CentOS 7. Tables that the query and stored function is using are small (less than 5k rows in each), so MySQL decides not to use the indexes (as shown in EXPLAIN).

Comment: @thatsaru - Start a new query, provide the query, the `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be subtle differences between your query and the one in this question.